# why auth.currentUser is null on page refresh in Firebase Authetication

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented Firebase Auth (Sign In With Google) in a MERN stack app.

The `/admin` client-side route is a protected route. After I log in, I see the displayName of the logged in user, as shown below:

[image]

Admin.js

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { getAuth, signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { useFetchAllPosts } from "../hooks/postsHooks";
import Spinner from "../sharedUi/Spinner";
import { PencilAltIcon } from "@heroicons/react/outline";
import { UserContext } from "../context/UserProvider";

const Admin = () => {
  const { data: posts, error, isLoading, isError } = useFetchAllPosts();

  const auth = getAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const { name } = useContext(UserContext);

  const handleLogout = () => {
    signOut(auth).then(() => {
      navigate("/");
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Hello {name}</h2>
      <button className="border" onClick={handleLogout}>
        Logout
      </button>
      <div>
        {isLoading ? (
          <Spinner />
        ) : isError ? (
          <p>{error.message}</p>
        ) : (
          posts.map((post) => (
            <div
              key={post._id}
              className="flex w-80 justify-between px-6 py-2 border rounded mb-4 m-auto"
            >
              <Link to={`/posts/${post._id}`}>
                <h2>{post.title}</h2>
              </Link>
              <Link to={`/posts/edit/${post._id}`}>
                <PencilAltIcon className="w-5 h-5" />
              </Link>
            </div>
          ))
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Admin;
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/screens/Home";
import PostCreate from "./components/screens/PostCreate";
import SinglePost from "./components/screens/SinglePost";
import Admin from "./components/screens/Admin";
import PostEdit from "./components/screens/PostEdit";
import Login from "./components/screens/Login";
import PrivateRoute from "./components/screens/PrivateRoute";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/admin" element={<PrivateRoute />}>
        <Route path="/admin" element={<Admin />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/posts/create" element={<PostCreate />} />
      <Route path="/posts/:id" element={<SinglePost />} />
      <Route path="/posts/edit/:id" element={<PostEdit />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default App;
```

PrivateRoute.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const auth = getAuth();

  console.log(auth.currentUser);

  return auth.currentUser ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Now, if I refresh this page, I go back to the `/login` route.

[image]

However, this should not happen, because if I go to the root `/` route, I see the displayName of the current user.

[image]

If I refresh the page while on the root `/` route, I still see the displayName of the current user.

**So, my question is why am I getting redirected to the `/login` page after I refresh the page on the `/admin` route?** I am logged in, so I should remain on the `Admin` page.

The logic of whether a user is logged-in or not is implemented in the `UserProvider` component:

UserProvider.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

export const UserContext = createContext();

const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);

  const auth = getAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user);
        setName(user.displayName);
      } else {
        setName(null);
      }
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [auth]);

  const user = {
    name,
    setName,
  };

  return <UserContext.Provider value={user}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
};

export default UserProvider;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution. I installed the `react-firebase-hooks` npm module and used the `useAuthState` hook to monitor the authentication status.

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";

const PrivateRoute = () => {

  const location = useLocation();

  const auth = getAuth();
  const [user, loading] = useAuthState(auth);

  if (loading) {
    return "Loading...";
  }

  return user ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase Authentication SDK automatically restores the user upon reloading the page/app. This does require a call to the server - a.o. to check if the account hasn't been disabled. While that verification is happening, `auth.currentUser` will be null.

Once the user account has been restored, the `auth.currentUser` will get a value, and (regardless of whether the restore succeeded or failed) any `onAuthStateChanged` listeners are called.

What this means is that you should not check the `auth.currentUser` value in code that runs immediately on page load, but should instead react to auth state changes with a listener.

If you need to route the user based on their authentication state, that should happen in response to the auth state change listener too. If you want to improve on the temporary delay that you get from this, you can consider implementing this trick that Firebaser Michael Bleigh talked about at I/O a couple of years ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwY6jkohseg&t=1311s

Comment: So, what should I do to remain on the Admin page and not get redirected to the Login page?